# Magento 2 : Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Customlogo_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I just installed a new magento theme and I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Customlogo_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/unilinxx.com/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php:547

So I opened that file.
This is the content:

```
 public static function helper($name)
 {
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass); // line 547
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
 }
```

I don't know what to do to fix this error.
My theme isn't working until this is fixed.

Comment: Find Module name with Customlogo and check if its `Helper/Data.php` file exists. Secondly make sure you have disabled the compilation before you install any new extension. Also try clearing your cache.

Comment: Where do I find this module?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what to do, Could you help me install a new theme in chat?

Comment: check if there is a folder named customlogo inside app/code/core/Mage

Comment: @AthulVijayan there is no folder named customlogo inside app/code/core/Mage  what should i do now?

Comment: @Priyank https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70096/help-with-installing-a-new-magento-theme

Comment: @JelleBotman look for the file having `customlogo` in name at `app/etc/modules` directory, if you did not found the file there then search for `helper('customlog')` in your theme's template directories

Comment: I removed helper('customlogo')

Comment: @JelleBotman after removing this , still issue is there?

Comment: yes still some issues